# Since when are users no longer able to view votes on their own pending edits?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits

I recall in the past that if you suggested an edit, and then clicked on the link to the review task, you would see that your edit was pending review/you were not able to review that item, but you could see any Approve/Reject votes of the pending edit before the review was actually completed. I have done some further investigation and found [some evidence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163558/1377755) that supports that this was actually the case.

However, currently, if we propose an edit and view the review task, we will just see that the suggested edit is pending review. We will only see the review votes (the reviewer, the review, and the timestamp) after the review is completed and the edit was either approved or rejected. Even if I loaded the page **after** the timestamp of any of the reviews that would be viewable after the review was completed.

However, I was not able to find any post announcing this change, or for what reason. I believe being able to see the progress of the suggested edit being reviewed was cool. I could not see how this could be used for abuse because there is no way to retract a suggested edit if you saw a reject vote anyway. A user could even correct their suggested edit (by editing again before their review was completed) if a user left a reject vote explaining a problem.

When was the change made that prevents users from viewing in-progress reviews of their pending edits, and why was this change necessary?

Comment: FWIW, there _is_ a (tedious) way to see this, at least on smaller sites: Go to `<site>.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats`, and visit each listed reviewer's profile, Activity>All Actions>Reviews, and comb through it to see whether they approved or rejected it. I doubt that would be feasible on SO, but it's worked for me on Hinduism, where most suggested edits seem to go into a void.

Comment: @CDR Yeah, I sometimes do things like that to see in-progress reviews. But I used to just be able to straight up view the reviews on my own suggested edits.

Comment: They aren't votes. They are approvals and rejections (sometimes unilateral).

Comment: I remebering noting the same change, but never bothered to chase it up on Meta. It feels like it changed *around* a year ago, it's been a while, at least.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Well, I have seen them been referred to as 'votes' at some point.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJYkX.png